# How to add ObjectId property to each object of an array

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I am have manually created an object in a Mongo collection:

```
{
    "messages": [
         {
            "url":"http://test.test.com", 
            "message":"test message"
         }
    ],

    ....other properties
}
```

I would like to add an `_id:ObjectId()` to each item of my messages array and for each document in the collection.

I tried:

```
collection.update({}, {
                     $set: {
                         'messages.$._id': ObjectId(),
                     },
                 }, { multi: true }
```

but this is not working.  The Id is getting added when I add new ones going through Mongoose, but these were manually entered into mongo.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is correct, but in order to use the $ positional operator the array field must appear as part of the query document, [check in documentation.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#definition)

Try this:

```js
db.collection.update({messages: {$exists: true }}, 
                     {$set: { 'messages.$._id': ObjectId() } },
                     {multi: true}
)
```

Comment: All of my data has a messages array with data in them....no need to make sure it exists.

Comment: Check carefully my answer, You need to include the array field in the query, in order to use the $ operator, that's why, an easy solution is to check for existence of messages field.